# Borders css/html

Tags: html, css, border

I have a problem with the css for my web page. Basically, I want to make it so when you hover over one of the links in the navigation bar, it puts a border around it. So, this is what I made:

```
     a
     {
       text-align: center;
       font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;;
       font-size: 20px;
       font-weight: bold;
       color: #4096ee;
       text-decoration: none;
       postion: absolute;
     }
     a:visited
      {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #4096ee;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
     a:hover
     {
     font-weight: bold;
     border-radius: 5px;
     color: #4096ee;
     padding: 4px;
     border: solid 2px;
     border-color: #303030;
     text-decoration: none;
     }
     a:active
     {
     font-weight: bold;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
     }
```

And then I have 4 links on the same line with 4 &emsp in between them. Now, whenever I hover over a link, the border appears, but  it kind of nudges the other links over to make space for the border. Is there any way I can stop this from happening?

Comment: 3 copy and paste answers and nobody has realised the double `;;` after the `font-family`

Answer (score 1):

why dont you put a border on the items and make it the same color as your background and simply change color on hover

Answer (score 0):

try adding `box-sizing : border-box`  to your css. This would make the border to go inside the element.

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS like this:

```
     a
     {
       text-align: center;
       font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;;
       font-size: 20px;
       font-weight: bold;
       color: #4096ee;
       text-decoration: none;
       postion: absolute;
       border-radius: 5px;
       padding: 4px;
       border-color: transparent;
     }
```

This way there will be no nudging.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a padding to the regular links. The hover state will override the regular padding and add the border.

```
a {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #4096ee;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px;
    postion: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5dQL5/

Answer (score 0):

```
   a{
       text-align: center;
       font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;;
       font-size: 20px;
       font-weight: bold;
       color: #4096ee;
       text-decoration: none;
       postion: absolute;
       border: 2px solid transparent;
     }
```

Just add a border with the same width (in your case 2px) but make it transparent and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Add default `2px` `border` to `anchor` tag, but make it `tranparent`. So it will not visible at first time when page is loaded. Then when you hover any anchor tag, change the `border-color` to `#303030`

Try this code

```
a{ 
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
a:hover{
  border-color: #303030;
}
```

Comment: Thanks gung, I made the changes as per your suggestion.